# How can I build a progressive web app using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, heroku, ssl-certificate, progressive-web-apps

I am currently working on a nodejs application with bootstrap as frontend and mongodb as a database . I have hosted my app on heroku. But it runs on http protocol . I want to make my site progressive for this I need to have an ssl certificate for my website how do I achieve this Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a free SSL certificate using the following method:
Create a free account on cloudflare and sign up for a free plan. In cloudflare, Copy the DNS. Then set the DNS in your domain service provider (godaddy or sth), then change the Cname config for the website inside cloudflare. Now you have a free certificate!

Comment: Can you explain it properly step by step  I am not getting it

Comment: Okay, so the first thing you need to do is to create an account in cloudflare. Then you need to head over to your domain manager (assuming you purchased a domain, godaddy, squarespace, google domains etc). There will be domain settings, you need to alter these to point to cloudflare DNS. In Cloudflare settings, you need to point to your heroku endpoint. 

So, it goes: 
Godaddy(or your domain provider) -> cloudflare -> Heroku

Look at this link to see the process in more detail:
https://thoughtbot.com/blog/set-up-cloudflare-free-ssl-on-heroku